# Sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^i\frac{x^{2i+1}}{2i+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone help me with this series? It was on my exam and I don't know how to do it.

For $|x| < 1$ determine the sum of
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty  (-1)^i\frac{x^{2i+1}}{2i+1}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative of the given sum is the geometric sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-x^2)^n=-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=-1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
so the given sum which vanish at $0$ is
$$\int_0^x\left(-1+\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt=-x+\arctan x$$

Comment: nice avatar needs nice attention, Sami

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? What would be the difference if the sum is from $0$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @James We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-x^2)^n=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @James Surely between the two sums there is a term more.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Expand $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ using the familiar $\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+y^3+\cdots$, and integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$.  Then adjust for the fact your sum starts at $i=1$.